# Reading in only a select number of files from a folder

Tags: r

I have a folder with approximately 50,000 textfiles. I only want to read in approximately 6,000 of these files, depending on the name of the file. All files are numbered so 5.txt, 16.txt etc.

Here's my attempt:

```
library(plyr)
library(qpcR)

files.content <- list.files("~/RFiles/user", "*.txt", full.names=T)
ID <- as.character(unique(ratings.df$RID))
# take the ID from a column of a dataframe further down in script 
# [1] "18617" "31213" "31203" "14975" "14749" "31192" etc

read.data <- function(x) {
  num <- as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]", "", x, perl=T))
  # gives me a list of numbers from folder

  select.files <- if(num %in% ID) {
    x1 <- file(x, open="rt")
    x2 <- readLines(x1, warn=F, encoding="UTF-8")
    x3 <- c(num, x2)
  }
}

table.files <- lapply(files.content, read.data) 
temp.vec <- do.call(qpcR:::rbind.na, table.files)

table.df <- data.frame(temp.vec, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Anyone got any better suggestions? It still reads the 50,000 files into the dataframe for some reason, not the selected 6,000.

EDIT: altered 10,000 back to 50,000.

Comment: Are the numbers completely sequential? Like from `1.txt` to `10000.txt`?

Comment: @merlin2011 thanks for pointing this out I've made a mistake I put 10,000 but actually it's 50,000. Hence why some of the ID's are greater than 10,000. Will edit it now. And yes the files from the folder are sequential.

Comment: could you describe maybe in words what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @Яaffael ID is a column from a dataframe that contains approx 6,000 names of the 50,000 files in my folder. I have been given the IDs in advance. I wish to read-in with the read.data function these very same 6,000 files from my folder (you see the IDs only contains the names of the files, not the files themselves). Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: then I don't understand the problem - you just read in all files with names (those IDs) provided by your data frame - looping through them. If you don't know how to read a file, then that is your actual question

Comment: @Яaffael Here's my problem more specifically - the reading of the files is not a problem. But I only want to read in 6,000 of the 50,000. So I run my script as above and it works - for 5950 of the files. For the remaining 50 or so files, it just gives me NA. Then it fills in the rest of the dataframe (44,000 values) with NA. I don't want that. I want the loop to read the 6,000 only (and correctly!) so I'm not sure what the problem is with the function read.data. Does it look Ok to you?

Comment: I'd rather assume there is a problem with YOUR files ... how about digging into that and trying to keep the bad files from being read in the first place?

Comment: I will investigate my files further. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Subset the files to read before running the function in lapply. I would guess that the rbind.na in your do.call is reading a blank element generated from lapply on the extra 44k files and sticking in all those NA's. Anyway, here is some basic subsetting code:

```
# create similar matching scenario
files <- paste0(1:200,'.txt')
id <- sample(files,50,replace = F)
id <- gsub('\\.txt','',id)

# subset the files needed; change regex to your case
index <- sub('[^0-9]*([0-9]{1,5})\\.txt','\\1',files) %in% id
filestoread <- files[index]

# however you need to read in, this is not tested
table.files <- lapply(filestoread,readLines,open = file(x, open="rt"),warn = F,encoding = "UTF-8")

# end with do.call and data.frame
```

And a side note, I skimmed the rbind.na documentation and it appears to give you a bunch of extra NA rows to make each data frame the same size. i.e. rbind.na two data.frames of 10 rows and 1000 rows, and you'll end up with 1010 rows of data and 990 rows of NA. Regular rbind will just give you 1010 of data which is usually what is wanted. In your case, that's 6k data.frames of data, 44k data.frames of all NA, each the size of your biggest file. rbind might just skip your blank elements as well on your original code.